# how to create a histogram with a character value and a numeric value?

Tags: r, histogram

I need to create a histogram so i have been using the function `hist()` and as the arguments I have tried various things. My aim is to create a different bar on the histogram for each row of the first column of my data.

```
####Example code that I have used: 
hist(bs223_[1, 2]) #to represent the first row of the second column.
####Error in hist.default(bs223_[1, 2]) : 'x' must be numeric
```

I believe this error is due to the values in the different rows are character values not numeric, as they contain the different names for some genes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not attach example code or data as an image (of course the sketch for the desired plot is OK). Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , especially the 'Help others reproduce the problem' part.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a histogram only? or can you try a barplot instead? below is the code.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.catplot(x='Col', y='H1', data=data2, kind='bar')
list1 = [10,650]
plt.yticks(list1)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: df_encoded.loc[:,'Col']=df_encoded.loc[:,'Col'].apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform